# Show that f is not differentiable at the origin of the following function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

Show that f is not differentiable at the origin of the following function:

$f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{matrix}\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}, (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\ 0, (x,y) = (0,0) \end{matrix}\right.$

I was thinking that I would have to approach the origin from the left and right of the x and y-axis.

But given that it is a conditional function I have myself confused.

Could someone show me how to approach this question. Thanks !

Comment: Try approaching along other lines: $x=y$ is a good start.

Comment: @ArnaudD. It is a duplicate, but if it matters, this one is 5 months older than the duplicate you've pointed to.

Answer (score 2):

If $y=mx$ we have
$$f(x,mx)=\frac{2m x^2}{x^2+m^2 x^2}=\frac{2m}{1+m^2}$$
Then the limit depends by direction m and the function isn't continue. Therefore it isn't differentiable.